# Binning to create categorical variable to be used as a factor in ANOVA

Tags: anova, two-way

I measured students' motivation using a likert type questionnaire and I want to check its effects on some dependent variables in a factorial ANOVA analysis. I wonder if it is okay to create categorical variables from it (e.g., low vs high motivated) and use it as a one factor in the analysis. Is this valid?

Comment: This is exceptionally poor statistical practice.  See [this](https://discourse.datamethods.org/t/categorizing-continuous-variables).

Comment: @FrankHarrell thanks for the resource! Then, for example, how could I identify levels of motivation?

Comment: Not sure what _identify_ and _levels_ means.  If you have sufficient sample size I would model degree of motivation using a flexible nonlinear function such as a regression spline and plot the estimated relationship between degree of motivation and the response variable.  This is detailed [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/genreg.html).